# MySQL limit on child

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I saw some articles but I can't implement it on my code,

I Have 3 tables

Category

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | winter |
| 2 | summer |

Product

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | bikini |
| 2 | scarf |

Category_product

| id_category | id_product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

Basically like that, with much more products and more records on category_product as well, so what I want is to select 10 categories with their products but limited by 10 as well...
So I have something like

```
---Category 1
      Product 1
      Product 2
      Product 3
---Category 2
      Product 1
      Product 2
      Product 3
```

10 category max and 10 products max

I tried this but only get one product

```
SELECT c.* FROM category c
INNER JOIN category_product cp ON cp.id_category = c.id 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT id_category, MAX(id_product) test
        FROM category_product
        GROUP BY id_category) cp2 ON cp.id_category = cp2.id_category
        AND cp.id_product = cp2.test
```

Comment: Interesting seasonal choices

Answer (score 0):

> so what I want is to select 10 categories with their products but limited by 10 as well

You can use `row_number()` and `limit`:

```
select c.*, cp.product_id
from (select c.*
      from categories c
      limit 10      -- you might want order by to get particular categories
     ) c join
     (select cp.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cp.category_id order by cp.product_id) as seqnum
      from category_product cp
     ) cp
     on c.category_id = c.id
where seqnum <= 10;
```

You can join in `products` if you want additional information about the products.